# Read a binary file in Java

Tags: java, php, binary, unpack

I have a java program that stores a byte array of 128 bytes length in a MySQL "BINARY (128)" field.

Then, with PHP I access to the database and I give the option to export this data into a file, so I unpack() the binary data, and write it into a file.

This file then, has to be read in a Java program that I am writing, but I can't find how I have to read this data. Any suggestion?

I tried with:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int i = 0;
while (i < 128) {
  System.out.println(baos.read());
  i++;
}
```

But bis.read() returns an int, and the byte array I sent to the mysql db was a string: "text".getBytes("utf-8");

Thank you,

Comment: A ByteArrayOutputStream is only for outputting/writing. It doesn't have a read() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine the answers of @Ricardo and @MarcoS

```
 DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("my-data-file.dat"));
 try {
     byte[] bytes = new byte[128];
     dis.readFully(bytes);
     // read some more.

 } finally {
     try {
        dis.close();
     } catch(IOException ignored) { }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a FileInputStream? (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)

The read() method reads a byte, though it returns an int.

Comment: +1: Best to use references to Java 6 Javadocs as both Java 1.4 and 5.0 are EOL now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with [Data Streams](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/datastreams.html)?