# Byte extraction in java

Tags: java, byte, extract, extaudiofile

I want to extract the bytes from a wav file in Java and I don't know how. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
public class AudioFiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file= new File("audio.wav");
        Scanner s= new Scanner(file);
        System.out.println(s.nextLine());
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489903/java-fileinputstream)

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489903/java-fileinputstream

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read a binary file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470812/read-a-binary-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

To read a `.wav` file as bytes in Java, you can use the java.io package to create an input stream from the .wav file and then read the bytes from the input stream.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       byte[] bytes = fileToBytes("/yourPath/audio.wav");
    }

    private static byte[] fileToBytes(String filePath) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        try(InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(file.toPath())) {
            inputStream.read(bytes);
        }
        return bytes;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream to read in bytes

> This is an InputStream which is specialized for reading audio files. In particular, it only allows operations to act on a multiple of the audio stream's frame size.

```
            File file = new File("audio.wav");
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            byte[] audioData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            audioInputStream.read(audioData);
```

OR `FileInputStream`:

> A FileInputStream obtains input bytes from a file in a file system. What files are available depends on the host environment.
> FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader.

```
        File file = new File("audio.wav");
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] bytes = inputStream.readAllBytes();//Read
```